# how to only update fields that are not empty with laravel 9

Tags: php, html

How to only update fields that are not empty with Laravel 9? I want to update the password if it is not empty, I use `$request->all()`.

I tried the used request()->all().

Answer (score 0):

You can check this: https://medium.com/@helmerdavila/laravel-update-only-blank-empty-fields-in-model-6946572aaab8

and to understand how it works, check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts

you can use **updateBlankOrCreate** (which you will add) just like **updateOrCreate**